# how to purge local maven repo and all maven caches

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to purge maven local repository ( ~/.m2/repository ) because of cache related issue in maven, the command i am using is
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false
but even after executing this command, i found all the jars in the local repository

I manually deleted the ~/.m2/repository and executed the same command but then maven started downloading the dependencies. Isn't this command supposed to delete and not download any transitive dependency?

Please tell me how exactly is it supposed to work

Comment: About what kind of cache related issues are you talking about? Please share the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

If your local repository is broken (for whatever reason), you can just delete `~/.m2/repository`

After that, you run whatever Maven command you want to run like `mvn clean verify`.